# Rails - Accessing Another Database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've set up a Rails app using MySQL, with the database 'DatabaseA'. My Rails app is a port of a PHP app that I've written earlier, so there's some data in the PHP app's database (DatabaseB) that I'd like to port over. It's not as simple as an export/import. I've made some schema changes to the database which would require me to manipulate the data first.

What would be the best way to do this? My ideal solution (in the past for PHP) would be to write another controller, and then quickly access DatabaseB and port the data to the new database.